# Error :$this->container

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying  to create a ws that send mail for client

In this function when I use `$this->get` container and I have this error:

> Call to a member function getParameter() on a non-object

Here is my code :

```
private function sendMailAlert($listeSuiveur, $listePostulant, $statut, $mission)
{
    $DateTimeFrench = new DateTimeFrench();

    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') ? "https://" : "http://";
    $missionurl = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/mission?id=' . $mission->getId();
    foreach ($listeSuiveur as $suiveur) {
        $messageToSend = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('notification suite au changement à la mission que vous suivez ')
            ->setFrom($this->container->getParameter('mail_address'), $this->container->getParameter('sender_name'))
            ->setTo($suiveur["email"])
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'Emails/notifieCandidat.html.twig',
                    array(
                        'statut' => $statut,
                        'missiontitre' => $mission->getTitre(),
                        'missiondescription' => strip_tags($mission->getDescription()),
                        'date'=>$DateTimeFrench->format($mission->getDatePublication()->format('d F Y ')),
                        'societe'=>$mission->getSociete()->getNom(),
                        'missionurl' => $missionurl,
                        'subject' => 'notification suite au changement à la mission ',
                        'sendername' => $suiveur["prenom"] . " " . $suiveur["nom"],
                    )
                ),
                'text/html'
            );
        $this->get('mailer')->send($messageToSend);
    }
}
```

and this is my `parameter.yml`:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:

    mail_address: noreply@test.com
    sender_name: 'test'
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Well, obviously `$this->container` is _not_ an object.

Comment: can you help me to resolve this error??

Comment: No, wen can't. We do not know your code, the class implementation. We have no idea where `$this->container` should come from. Only you can tell.

Comment: Can you please paste your full class here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is `$this`? And if it is a controller, what class does it extend?

Comment: Even if your get past the container issue, renderView is not going to work either.